# Java Swing JFrame to be rendered before moving on

Tags: java, swing, queue, jframe

I want to build a "Work in progress..."-JFrame before calling a method that might take some time but the JFrame won't be fully rendered before the method is executed.
I know I'm not the first with that problem, I always find solutions involving threads (do the long working method in a thread and so on). But I don't want to for particular reasons (and it might be that I'm not even able to unless I want the system to go boom).

So, is there a possibility to tell Swing to first render a window and then do the rest? Something like get rendering the window to be the first in the excecute-queue?

Comment: Assuming you could go down this road, what happens if the screen gets updated, moved, or overwritten?  Your JFrame won't repaint.  It is best to use threads.

Comment: `"But I don't want to for particular reasons (and it might be that I'm not even able to unless I want the system to go boom)."` -- Sorry but this makes no sense whatsoever. If you decline to use the proper solution for your problem, you'd best give us more detailed and strong reasons for not doing so.

Comment: There were some thread-safe issues. But I've settled for threads now since I don't see any other solution. And of course you are right, Hovercraft, it is a proper solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to do it by displaying the JFrame and then calling

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myLongMethod();
    }
});
```

But it's really a bad idea. The GUI will be frozen for the whole duration of the method.

The right way to do it is, indeed, to use a background thread. But Swing has all you need to make it painless. Simply use a [`SwingWorker`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). Its API doc is well-written and has examples. Try doing it, and if you can't, Ask another question and show the code you have tried so that someone helps you.

Answer (score 3):

maybe [How to Create a Splash Screen](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) ???